# Swift: How to access second view after navigation controller?

Tags: swift, navigationcontroller, tabbed

I'm really new to swift and currently working on a project for a trivia app.  Right now I have it so that after pressing the start button, it pushes aside the current view controller and shows the user a new one (vc), but I'm not sure how/where to add textfields and buttons to that new view (vc) that the user sees after pressing start.

```
       
       let vc = UIViewController()
       vc.view.backgroundColor = .red
       
       navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to create another view controller with UI in it.

```
   class SecondViewController: UIViewController {
       private let textView = UITextView()
       
       func viewDidLoad() {
           super.viewDidLoad()
           
           // Add text view with auto layout
           view.addSubview(textView)
           textView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
           textView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor).isActive = true
           textView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
           textView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 44).isActive = true
       }
   }
```

Then when trying to push a new view controller use this `SecondViewController`

```
   let vc = SecondViewController()
   vc.view.backgroundColor = .red
   
   navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
```

Answer (score 0):

you can declare view controller with the specified identifier

```
let vc = UIStoryboard.init(name: "Authentication", bundle: Bundle.main).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "Login") as? LoginVC
self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc!, animated: true)
```